# Wordpress CSS on post pages

Tags: css, wordpress

I have wordpress website, I have applied custom HTML on Home page for footer. It appears well but on the post page the footer is not appearing like it should as on the Home page.

I think there is some CSS which is missing. I am not able to figure this out. Please help.

Home page Screen shot : https://ibb.co/f5wZxx

POst page screen shot : https://ibb.co/mz6Zxx

I have made some changes on the code below as I cant reveal the brand name.

Code :

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="keywords" content="footer, address, phone, icons" />

<title>Footer With Address And Phones</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="wp-content/themes/oblique/inc/class/class-customizer-theme-info-control/css/style.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cookie" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

```
<body>

    <footer class="footer-distributed">

        <div class="footer-left">

        <p class="footer-links">
                <a href="#">Home</a>
                ·
                <a href="#">About</a>
                ·
                <a href="#">Contact</a>
            </p>

            <p class="footer-company-name">2018 | All Rights Reserved</p>
        </div>

        <div class="footer-center">
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                <p><a href="#">Official website - Español</a></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-globe"></i>
                <p><a href="#">Official website - English</a></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                <p><a href="mailto:#"></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-right">
            <p class="footer-company-about">
                <span>About </span>
            </p>
            <div class="footer-icons">
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>              
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, you might want to provide a code sample. What exactly did you insert where?

Comment: `I am not able to figure this out.` Even we can't figure it out without seeing your code. You have to share your code.

Comment: Hi I have added the code..

Comment: @AshishSahani can you share screenshot of the issue. And without CSS we can figure out what's the issue.

Comment: @Selvam I have added the screen shots

Comment: @Selvam - I think the CSS is not getting picked up on the post page. while it does on Home page

Comment: @AshishSahani, yes you're correct! can you check the CSS file path btwn home and post page ? if possible share both page source code too.

Comment: Best practice is to add the CSS in functions.php like this `wp_enqueue_style ('theme-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css');` and remove it from the header. This way you wont encounter any issues with it.

Comment: Please share related styles (*.css). It seems like problem might be related to css seletors. Also check browser dev tools for computed and applied style rules for your concerned node/selector.

Comment: @Asad - Please see css from here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lEfo9YqWASrzU1Tl2uS9dxQClYjqWGpm

Comment: @ Selvam - Please see source code from here - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lEfo9YqWASrzU1Tl2uS9dxQClYjqWGpm